# What is the Oracle error code (ORA-) for a Query Timeout?

Tags: database, oracle, ora-12170

I need to know whats the oracle QUERY timeout error code.

I know the code ORA-12170, but this code is an TNS connect timeout. I need the Query timeout.

I looked in many places and not find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ORA-01013 - user requested cancel of current operation

This is the message and code which you will get when the timeout happens.

Comment: Thanks! I searched by ORA-01013 and you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not agree with you. When you hit an ORA-01013, it's because you have no more temp space to execute your query.

ORA-01555: snapshot too old is more appropriate.  It's caused by Oracle read consistency mechanism.